# Bootstrap tagsinput with angular ng-model issue

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, bootstrap-tags-input

I have an angular form that is creating an object with tags:

```
<form class="form-horizontal">
 <div class="form-group">
  <label>Tags</label>
  <input type="text" id="tags-input" class="form-control" ng-model="beaconData.tag_list" name="beacon[tag_list]" placeholder="project, client 72, yellow, design"/>
 </div>
```

The id "#tags-input" is calling the tagsinput function as seen here:

```
$('#tags-input').tagsinput('items');
```

With the id calling this function the ng-model="beaconData.tag_list" returns undefined. If the  tagsinput function is not called the ng-model returns the data with no problem.

<strike>Does anyone might have an answer as to why this is happening?</strike>

The better question might be what does the tagsinput function do to the input values and why does it not return back to ng-model?

Comment: When you don't have this jQuery code model is filled with data?

Comment: Correct, this jQuery code does format the tags in the input field though

Comment: Can you maybe share more of your js code? Cause this one line does not seem to be anyhow connected to that beaconData.

Comment: That's it. I've narrowed the issue down to that tagsinput function which is part of a framework. The file for that function is here:
[Tagsinput](https://github.com/bootstrap-tagsinput/bootstrap-tagsinput/blob/master/src/bootstrap-tagsinput.js)

Comment: When i get it correctly, your fields are filled by this tags input plugin but they are not reflected into model?

Comment: Yes, that is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

With the help of a coworker, I was able to grab the values of the spans that tagsinput spits out and insert that into my object for saving.

```
    var tags = angular.element('.form-group div').children('span').map(function (i, s) { return angular.element(s).text(); });
```